# What is distributed firewall?

Tags: firewall

What is distributed firewall? What are the problems associated with conventional firewall that gave rise to distributed firewall? Are there any kind of attacks that can be prevented by using distributed firewall?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

As you can imagine, distributed firewalls were born out of necessity of scaling out the performance of firewalling services. While one central firewall, clustered (or whatever) can today handle usually up to multiple of 10Gbit/s streams, distributed firewall can in theory scale to unlimited bandwidth - as long as you can instantiate/install next units and synchronize configuration (and sometimes also state) between them. The policy you define once is synchronized across all access network entities, and appropriate filtering takes place across all ports of a network.

As for examples - Cisco VSG with Nexus 1000v is distributed firewall, just like the newest VMWare NSX firewall.

Answer (score 3):

I know something about this topic and am happy to answer :-)

### What is a distributed firewall?

A distributed firewall is a security architecture used to protect hosts on a network.  (Some might argue with the term 'architecture' here and prefer the word 'design'.)

### What are the problems associated with conventional firewalls that gave rise to distributed firewalls?

A conventional firewall architecture forces network traffic through a single 'choke point' - the firewall itself.  There is therefore a fundamental requirement on that particular topology, and there are number of inherent disadvantages as a consequence.  These include:

- The interactions that occur purely *between* the hosts on the network cannot be filtered, since the firewall cannot observe that traffic.
- Some hosts require more access to the "outside" (such as the Internet) than others.  This requirement then has to be built into the network architecture and the arrangement of hosts (such as with a DMZ arrangement).
- There is a tendency for the ruleset of a firewall that protects large numbers of hosts to become very complex over time. (See the work of Prof. Avishai Wool from Tel Aviv University on this topic.)
- The firewall has to either terminate or proxy end-to-end encrypted traffic that traverses the firewall in order to inspect the content of that encrypted traffic.

In the distributed firewall model, each host on the network is responsible for filtering the traffic that it individually receives.  In theory, this ameliorates the above problems.

### Are there any kind of attacks that can be prevented by using a distributed firewall?

A distributed firewall emphasizes the security of individual hosts. Particular scenarios in which the distributed model might therefore be advantageous include:

- Attacks between hosts, i.e. that occur within the network perimeter.
- Malicious insiders that are by-definition already within the network perimeter.
- Attacks that defeat or compromise a perimeter firewall (e.g. Mike Schiffman and Dave Goldsmith's 'Firewalking' technique.)

I will also note that the distributed firewall idea, although interesting, has not found much real-world traction.  Perimeter firewalls are still pervasive.  It might be possible to argue that distributed firewalls were the precursor to network-enabled host-based configuration management, although this would probably be something of a stretch.

### Academic research

The early academic research on the topic of distributed firewalls was carried out by Steven M. Bellovin (who is also the co-author of the book *Firewalls & Internet Security*). The two most notable papers by Bellovin on the topic of distributed firewalls are:

1. [Distributed Firewalls](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/papers/distfw.pdf) (1999)
2. [Implementing a Distributed Firewall](https://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/papers/ccs-df.pdf) (2000)

If you're interested in reviewing additional academic research you can perform a search on Microsoft's Academic Search service for "distributed firewall", which currently returns 77 results.

I hope this is useful. Best of luck to you!